# Power BI's Conditional Foramatting works wrong for first level in drill down

Tags: powerbi, conditional-formatting, gantt-chart

I have a matrix which is used to show a kind of Gantt chart. In the first level, I show the users in column and dates in rows and by clicking on each name, We navigate to the second level to show tasks of that user and change the background color of busy dates for her/him.
If I set the rule in the conditional formatting based on the status column, in the first level of Gantt chart, We see just one color for all of the time line; however we must see the color separately in this line because of the different value in status column. The colors in front of tasks is OK and works properly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you see in the second image, when we close the task of first user, the colors are showing wrongly and just by one color, however I saw proper color in level of tasks.

Do you have any idea to solve that?
Regards

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: @mkRabbani I updated the question. An image is added